# Should a bijection be defined as two-way injection or a surjection and injection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

The definitions of a surjection and injection make intuitive sense to me from the etymology of sur and in. Likewise for a bijection when defined as a two-way injection between two sets where the bi comes from Latin for two.

However, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection) article defines a bijection as:

> (That is, the function is both injective and surjective.)

Yes, this is an equivalent definition for a bijection, but was this the intention of the original definition, and is this how it's first presented to students?

Comment: As far as I know, the "bi" in "bijection" refers to "Two" in the sense of the two properties "injective" and "surjective".

Comment: I agree with @AndreasBlass . I've never thought about a "two way injection" and see no way to define it without invoking surjectivity.

Comment: If we just have two injections $A\to B$ and $B\to A$, they don't (trivially) induce a bijection.

Comment: I have only ever seen "bijection" defined as "a single map which is both injective and surjective."